# Cannot pass arguments while Hosting a iosView in Flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I am trying to host a `iOS UIImageView` to display QR code in a `Flutter` app. I am able to get the qr display correctly. Now I want to pass extra arguments from `flutter` to `iOS native side`

Below is my `flutter` code

```
class CealQrView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CealQrView({required this.text, super.key});

  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Pass parameters to the platform side.
    final Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = <String, dynamic>{};
    creationParams["text"] = text;

    return  UiKitView(
            viewType: cealQrView,
            layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            creationParams: creationParams,
            creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
          );
  }
}
```

As you can see I am passing `creationParams` from `flutter` side to `native iOS` side

Below is my iOS code

```
class FLNativeViewFactory: NSObject, FlutterPlatformViewFactory {
    private var messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger

    init(messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger) {
        self.messenger = messenger
        super.init()
    }

    func create(
        withFrame frame: CGRect,
        viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
        arguments args: Any?
    ) -> FlutterPlatformView {
        return FLNativeView(
            frame: frame,
            viewIdentifier: viewId,
            arguments: args,
            binaryMessenger: messenger)
    }
}


class FLNativeView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {
    private var _view: UIView
    
    init(
        frame: CGRect,
        viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
        arguments args: Any?,
        binaryMessenger messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
    ) {
        _view = UIView()
        super.init()
        // iOS views can be created here
        debugPrint("Arguments ")
        debugPrint(args)
        debugPrint(messenger)
        
        if let args = args as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
           let textValue = args["text"] as? String {
            // please check the "as" above  - wasn't able to test
            // handle the method
            debugPrint(textValue)          } else {
                debugPrint("Else")
            }
        
        
        debugPrint("\(viewId)")
        createNativeView(view: _view)
    }
    
    func view() -> UIView {
        return _view
    }
    
    func createNativeView(view _view: UIView){
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: 100,height: 100)
        imageView.image = generateQRCode(from: "Hello")
        _view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    
    func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
        
        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
            
            if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
                return UIImage(ciImage: output)
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

I am trying to print in `init` block of `FLNativeView` but I always get `args` as nil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this method :

```
public func createArgsCodec() -> FlutterMessageCodec & NSObjectProtocol {
          return FlutterStandardMessageCodec.sharedInstance()
    }
```

Inside your `FLNativeViewFactory` like this

```
class FLNativeViewFactory: NSObject, FlutterPlatformViewFactory {
    private var messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger

    init(messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger) {
        self.messenger = messenger
        super.init()
    }


public func createArgsCodec() -> FlutterMessageCodec & NSObjectProtocol {
          return FlutterStandardMessageCodec.sharedInstance()
    }

    func create(
        withFrame frame: CGRect,
        viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
        arguments args: Any?
    ) -> FlutterPlatformView {
        return FLNativeView(
            frame: frame,
            viewIdentifier: viewId,
            arguments: args,
            binaryMessenger: messenger)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks man. This is what was missing for me =)